# Is it possible to apply formatting based on certain conditions in MS Word?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2010

I have a huge document in which I want to ensure that if any text has following attributes, then it should be set as Heading 1.

Attributes are:
Font: Calibri
Font Size: 12
Bold

How can this be done in MS Word?

Comment: What version of Word and what have you tried?

Comment: Microsoft Office 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "Heading 1"? Should the text be converted to a header?
You can search text that matches your criteria by using Word's search and replace feature. Then replace them accordingly. Follow this [guide](http://www.geekhowtos.com/search-and-replace-specific-formatting-fonts-styles-etc-in-microsoft-word/).

**Edit**

1.Start recording a macro. See [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/create-macros-in-word-2010/) for help.Do set a shortcut key to start the same.
2.Find any text in the file that matches your criteria (Using the above process).
3.Click on the *Heading 1* style to apply the style.
4.Stop the macro.
5.Now press the shortcutkey to start the macro again. It should automatically change all matching text to the styleset.

Comment: Good answer. You've almost got it. `Heading 1` is a font style on the Home tab, not the header of the document. To improve your answer quality, please ask questions in the comment area below the original post. Once you have clarification, post your answer accurately.